# DISM unable to repair Server 2016

Tags: windows-server-2016, windows-update, dism

I've been fighting this for a few days now and could really use some help from the community.  This started out as a failure to install windows updates on a Server 2016 Datacenter, which led to indications that there was an issue with CBS store corruption. SFC /ScanNow comes back clean, dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /CheckHealth shows that the component store is repairable.
[CheckHealth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e41mP.png)

Running dism.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /Source:WIM:C:\temp\install.wim:1 /LimitAccess /Loglevel:4 eventually fails with Error: 0x800f081f.
[Source WIM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMoZO.png)

For reference install.wim:1 is confirmed as the Windows Server 2016 Datacenter wim, from Microsoft's portal.
[Wim Index Verification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VE51W.png)

Attempting the repair without specifying a source results in an almost more unusual Error: 14 "Not enough storage is available to complete this operation."; the OS drive has 44 GB of space free.
[Error 14](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CL1Pv.png)

The dism.log doesn't seem to have much of value, but CBS.log has "Failed to download updates [HRESULT = 0x8007000e - E_OUTOFMEMORY]" which on the Timeline matches the Error 14.

Also from CBS.log:

```
Checking System Update Readiness.

(p) CSI Payload Corrupt         amd64_microsoft-windows-msmq-powershell_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.14393.1066_none_3ecfc4b3ae7c6dae\Microsoft.Msmq.Runtime.Interop.dll
Repair failed: Missing replacement payload.
(p) CSI Payload Corrupt         amd64_microsoft-windows-msmq-powershell_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.14393.1066_none_3ecfc4b3ae7c6dae\Microsoft.Msmq.Activex.Interop.dll
Repair failed: Missing replacement payload.
(p) CSI Payload Corrupt         amd64_microsoft-windows-msmq-powershell_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.14393.1066_none_3ecfc4b3ae7c6dae\Microsoft.Msmq.PowerShell.Commands.dll
Repair failed: Missing replacement payload.
(p) CSI Payload Corrupt         x86_microsoft-windows-msmq-powershell_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.14393.1066_none_e2b1292ff61efc78\Microsoft.Msmq.Activex.Interop.dll
Repair failed: Missing replacement payload.
(p) CSI Payload Corrupt         x86_microsoft-windows-msmq-powershell_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.14393.1066_none_e2b1292ff61efc78\Microsoft.Msmq.PowerShell.Commands.dll
Repair failed: Missing replacement payload.
(p) CSI Payload Corrupt         amd64_microsoft-windows-fsrm-service_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.14393.1378_none_167ee64821565098\srmsvc.dll
Repair failed: Missing replacement payload.
```

These appear to be my culprits, but I cannot find these in the winsxs directory on a brand new Server 2016 that I have also attempted to use as the source for the repair.

I'm not sure what else to try, Microsoft's documentation on this is running me in circles saying that sfc and DISM are the answer.

Comment: Can you check if the build of Windows in the WIM matches the build running on your server? `dism /Get-WimInfo /WimFile:c:\temp\install.wim /index:1`  

Next thing you can try is to apply to your offline windows image the latest cumulative updates you installed on your server, the goal is to have identical windows versions between the offline image and the online windows server.Then, try to repair again with the updated offline source.

Comment: Hi @Swisstone, can confirm that the builds are identical for the wim and the installed OS.  That did get me to a point of tracking down the build associated with the corrupt files.  The build 10.0.14393.1066 for the missing files appears to mtach KB4015217, which is no longer available in the windows update catalog.  

I was able to find these files by looking for a server that was build around the same time, and have imported them and successfully repaired the CBS store corruption.  The server still won't update, but my original question is resolved at least.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately the solution for the dism restorehealth failures was identifying the KB associated with the missing files in the winsxs folder.  In my case these missing files were from KB4015217, which is no longer available on the windows update catalog.  Fortunately I was able to find another server that was built around the same time that had received this particular KB.  I copied the "missing" files from the source server to my affected system and re-ran the dism commands to restore health.